# iOS開発でのMVCとは

Tags: swift, ios, model-view-controller

私は、一人で開発していたためMVCなどはあまり気にせず開発を行っていました。
しかし、チーム開発を行うことになったため、その開発手法をどうしようか悩んでおります。

まずはMVCだろう。
ということでネットでiOSにおけるMVC開発手法を調べたのですがどうにもしっくりきません。

こちらのサイトも参考になるのですが、
[これが最強のMVC(iOS)](http://qiita.com/koitaro/items/b3a924245fd72f22871a)
このかたの開発手法ですと、どうやら「Modelの再利用ができない」そうなのです。
それってダメなんじゃないの？と、素人の私は思っております。

iOSでのMVCの実現はどうすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*iOSでのMVCの実現はどうすればよいでしょうか。*
やはり、iOSの開発元であるAppleのドキュメントを当たっておくべきでしょう。

[Cocoa Core Competencies/Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1)
AppleがMVCをどう捉えているか、図とともに簡単な解説があります。

[iOSアプリケーション プログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf)
([App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html))
「アプリケーションの構成」の節の中で、iOSアプリで使用されるオブジェクトをModel/View/Controllerに分けて分類した図があります。

[Objective-Cプログラミングの概念](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/CocoaEncyclopedia.pdf)
([Concepts in Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introduction/Introduction.html))
ご質問内のリンク先でも参照されていますが、「Model-View-Controllerパターン」と言う章にApple流のMVCの解説があります。但し、OS X用として書かれたものにiOS用の修正を施した形ですのでiOSに用意されたフレームワークにはうまく当てはまらない内容も含まれています。

[Model-View-Controller for iPhone OS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2010/116/)
少し古いですが、WWDC 2010でのセッションビデオです。英語音声のみの1時間近いビデオですが、iOSでのMVCについて考えるならば一度は目を通しておくべきでしょう。英語音声がわからなければpdf資料に目を通すだけでもざっくりとした感覚は掴めると思います。
　ビデオは10のBest Tipsという構成ですが、その中のDO NOTの部分を開発メンバーに徹底しておくだけでも、かなり有効ではないかと思います。

> The 10 Best MVC Tips Ever
>   #1. Learn MVC for iPhone OS
>   #2. Use MVC to Divide Work
>   #3. Don't Fight the Framework
>
> - Don't misuse framework classes
>     (フレームワークにあるクラスの誤った利用をしてはいけない)
> - Don't re-implement framework classes
>      (フレームワークにあるクラスの再実装を行ってはいけない)
> - Don't make trivial UIKit subclasses
>      (UIKitの自明なサブクラスを作ってはいけない)
>
> #4. Don't Abuse Views
>
> - xxx Views Don't Own Data xxx
>      (ビューがデータを保持してはいけない…かなり強調されています)
>
> #5. Plan for iPhone and iPad
>    #6. Strive for Loose Coupling
>
> - Don't skip MVC layers when messaging
>     (オブジェクト間のメッセージのやり取りでMVCの階層をスキップしてはいけない)
> - Don't mix MVC roles in one object
>     (MVCの役割を一つのオブジェクトに混在させてはいけない)
> - Don't declare model data in your view classes
>     (ビュークラスの中でモデルデータを宣言してはいけない)
>
> #7. Choose the Right Data Model
>
> - x Defaults/Preferences
>     (デフォールト/設定をデータモデルに使うのはダメ)
>
> #8. Decompose Controller Work
>
> - Avoid making EverythingControllers
>     (「なんでもコントローラー」を作るのは避けること)
> - x Class checks in delegate methods
>     (デリゲートメソッドの中でクラス判定をするなんてのはダメ)
>
> #9. Take Charge of Your Object Graph 
>   #10. Coordinate State Changes
>
> - Don't Cut Out the Controller
>     (コントローラーをすっ飛ばさない)

元ビデオ(pdf資料)を見れば、もう少し具体的に説明されているものもあります。わかりにくいところがあれば、まずは元ビデオを当たってください。

元ビデオではMVCパターンの恩恵として「Flexible and Easy to Change(柔軟で変更が容易)」なソフトウェアを作れることとしていますので、「Modelの再利用ができない」のではApple的MVCの観点からはとても最強とは言えないですね。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ビデオとても参考になりました。一つ伺いたいのですが #3. Don't Fight the Framework の Don't make trivial UIKit subclasses (自明なサブクラスを作ってはいけない)ということなのですが、例えばどういうことなのでしょうか、動画では Use delegates and notifications とあったのですが、よく理解できませんでした。

Comment: 他のオブジェクト指向言語ベースのUIフレームワークだと、フレームワークが提供するUIクラスの動作をカスタマイズするのはサブクラス化が基本だったりします。Cocoa/Cocoa Touchの場合、delegateやnotificationの機構を使えばサブクラス化を行わずに大抵の用途には対応できるように作られているので、「trivial」と言うのは「明らかにそれらが使えるような場合」と言うニュアンスでしょう。普通Apple製フレームワークに即した実装をすると自然にそうなるんで、サブクラス化が普通の他のフレームワークに慣れた人向けの言葉だと思います。